# How to pass some mouse events to item undeneath

Tags: html, svg, d3.js, events

I have an SVG item (created with d3). It contains a series of groups.

One group contains a series of circles, with titles (which the browser pops up automatically when you hold the mouse over the circle), and mouseover and click event handlers.

A group on top of that contains some lines joining some of the circles. These lines also have titles. When the user holds the mouse over a line, I want the title to pop up as usual. But when the user **clicks** on a line, I want that click to be ignored, and treated as if it was a click on whatever was underneath the line (which may be a circle).

I have done a lot of searches, but I can't see how to do that - the circle is not a parent or child of the line, so I don't think event bubbling helps.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68a7bdzn/2/) with a really simple example. I would like clicking on that part of a line inside a circle to run the click event of the circle.

```
svg = d3.select('svg')
  .style("cursor", "pointer")
//  .attr("viewBox", '0 0 500, 500')
;
circles = svg.append('g');
lines = svg.append('g');
events = d3.select('#events');
var data = [
    { id: 1, x: 25, y: 25 },
    { id: 2, x: 75, y: 25 },
    { id: 3, x: 25, y: 75 },
    { id: 4, x: 75, y: 75 }
];
circles.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
  .join('circle')
    .attr('cx', d=> d.x)
    .attr('cy', d=> d.y)
    .attr('r', 20)
    .on('click', function(e) { events.text('circle');})
  .append('title')
    .text(d=> 'circle ' + d.id)
    ;
lines.selectAll('line')
    .data(data, d => d.id)
  .join('line')
  .attr('x1', d=> d.x - 25)
  .attr('y1', d=> d.y - 25)
  .attr('x2', d=> d.x + 25)
  .attr('y2', d=> d.y + 25)
    .on('mouseover', function(e) { events.text('line');})
    .on('mouseout', function(e) { events.html('&nbsp;');})
  .append('title')
    .text(d=> 'line ' + d.id)
  ;
```

```
<div>
<svg></svg>
</div>
<div id='events'>
&nbsp;
</div>
<ul>
<li>Hover over yellow line to see 'line' above.</li>
<li>Click blue circle to see 'circle' above</li>
<li>I would like to see 'circle' appear when you click on that part of a line that is within a circle.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As always, some code demonstrating the issue would be helpful. Please try to set up a [mcve].

Comment: set pointer-events: none on the line

Comment: @RobertLongson Since the `<title>` element is a descriptive element it cannot become an event target when it comes to hit-testing. Therefore, setting `pointer-events: none` also disables the tooltips on the lines.

Comment: @altocumulus My comment was written before there was any code, which is also why I didn't write it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if there is a way to pass an event on to the item underneath the one clicked on?